# Android: Is there a way to convert a SoapObject (carrying XML data) to an InputStream object?

Tags: android, xml, inputstream, ksoap2, xmlpullparser

The `SoapObject` is the response from a SOAP based web service.

I know it contains `XML` data because I tested the web service on www.soapclient.com.

Now, I want to use `XMLPullParser` to parse the response. `XMLPullParser` takes an `InputStream`, so is there a way to convert the `SoapObject` into an `InputStream`?

Comment: why you wan to convert SOAP response to xml instead get prepare response data using SOAP getProperty() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may redefine envelope class by replacing parseBody method. Here is example of inheriting class:

```
public class SSEnv  extends SoapSerializationEnvelope
{
    public void parseBody(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException{

        //Yes! its modified code snipet from android dev page :)
         int eventType = parser.getEventType();

         while (!(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("body"))) {

          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("Start document");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              System.out.println("Start tag "+parser.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
              System.out.println("End tag "+parser.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
              System.out.println("Text "+parser.getText());
          }
          eventType = parser.next();
         }
    }
}
```

Remember that parse method from SoapEnvelope require end tag of "Body", thats why there is condition in loop "while (!(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("body")))". And ofcourse after getRequest and bodyIn will be null after that modification.

Second way is to parse reponseDump from HttpTransportSE but its a kind of terrorism ;)

kind regards
Marcin